# Powershell XML delete Nodes where ChildNode "Date" is older than a Month

Tags: xml, powershell, automation

I want to find all "message" Nodes in which the Date is older than a spezific Date and delete them.

If I'm using `$result = $xml.transcript.messages.message.date | Select-String -Pattern "2018-09-10"` I can find the Date Nodes I'm looking for, but i think $result is only a String and i'm not able to access the Parent Node and delete it.

```
<transcript>
 <messages>
  <message>
   <to>user1</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-05 11:56:50.961 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user1</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-10 15:26:50.299 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user2</to>
   <from>user1/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-12 09:38:01.997 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user1/Spark</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-12 09:38:19.382 MESZ</date>
  </message>
 </messages>
</transcript>
```

For those who know Spark IM, i basically just want to delete older messages via Powershell once a day.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This will return the `message` node:

```
$result = $xml.transcript.messages.message | Where-Object {$_.date -like "2018-09-10*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is invalid: `>` in `body` should be escaped. Fortunately PowerShell is not too restrictive. This should work:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<transcript>
 <messages>
  <message>
   <to>user1</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-08-05 11:56:50.961 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user1</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-10 15:26:50.299 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user2</to>
   <from>user1/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-12 09:38:01.997 MESZ</date>
  </message>
  <message>
   <to>user1/Spark</to>
   <from>user2/Spark</from>
   <body>>Message Bla Bla Bla</body>
   <date>2018-09-12 09:38:19.382 MESZ</date>
  </message>
 </messages>
</transcript>
'@
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true

$xml.SelectNodes('//message') | where { ([DateTime]$_.date.Substring(0, 23)) -lt [DateTime]::Now.AddMonths(-1) } | % {
    $xml.transcript.messages.RemoveChild($_)
}
```